# terminal bash - back command doesn't work

Tags: bash

I'm using a Mac OSX version 10.8

In bash prompt, When I try to go back a directory..I type b and the hit enter.
And I get this message:
bash: b: command not found

How can I get this command to work?

Comment: Try `cd ..` , also - Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Computer usage questions that don't relate to coding go on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use "b" as shortcut to go back in bash :

```
echo "alias b='cd ..'" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

That's for Mac OS X. If you want the same shortcut in Linux, you could replace the .bash_profile file by .bashrc

Comment: Great, you could mark your post as resolved ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ..
```

`cd` means change directory. You should read the result of `man cd`